# An error occured while downloading the index 'xdb' schema

Tags: xdb, xconnect

Our Production instance is hosted in Azure and getting so many failed requests with the below error. Not sure what could be the reason

**An error occured while downloading the index 'xdb' schema. Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).**

[image]

**Complete error from Azure:**

```
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Failures.AzureResponseException:
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.AzureResults.HttpResponseMessageExtensions+<EnsureSuccessfulResponse>d__0.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Schema.IndexDeployer+<GetIndexSchema>d__7.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Schema.IndexDeployer+<UpsertSchema>d__8.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.IndexingInitializer+<Initialize>d__11.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.SingleThreadedIndexer+<RunInThread>d__6.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
    Inner exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException handled at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.AzureResults.HttpResponseMessageExtensions+<EnsureSuccessfulResponse>d__0.MoveNext:
    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode (System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.AzureResults.HttpResponseMessageExtensions+<EnsureSuccessfulResponse>d__0.MoveNext (Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

Below error is recorded multiple times in Sitecore log. Not sure whether this is related anyway.

```
2844 2019:02:04 23:51:03 ERROR Cannot start analytics Tracker
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The certificate was not found.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.DataStorage.ReferenceDataClientDictionary.EnsureDefinitionType(String definitionTypeName)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.DataStorage.ReferenceDataClientDictionary.LoadAs[T](Object key)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.AverageCounterExtensions.MeasureMilliseconds[T](AverageCounter counter, Func`1 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.ReferenceDataDictionary`2.Get(TKey key, LookupStrategy strategy)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.UserAgentsDictionary.Register(String userAgentName)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.CurrentVisitContext.set_UserAgent(String value)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.InitializeWithRequestData.Process(CreateVisitArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.CreateVisitPipeline.Run(CreateVisitArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.CreateInteraction(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.CreateVisit.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.InitializeTrackerPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.StartTrackingPipeline.Run(StartTrackingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.StartTracking()
```

Comment: Have you checked if connectionstring for azure search contains apiKey? If it does, ensure that it's the same as the Admin key in your Azure Search Service.

Comment: @grg, yes both are same.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am facing the same one